# Modificar varios atributos de un objeto con un método

Tags: python, python-3.x, diccionarios, atributos

Tengo una lista con varios objetos que tienen varios atributos.
Mediante un método pretendo modificar ciertos atributos de un determinado objeto.
A este método uso `**args` para poder pasar los atributos y valores a modificar, por ejemplo `(nombre='nuevo nombre', ID=123, direccion='Madrid)` y que recorro como un diccionario. Pero no tengo claro como acceder eficientemente al atributo del objeto para modificarlo.

Este es el código:

```
def mod_objeto(self, nombre, **atrs):
    ''' Modifica los atributos de un objeto'''

    # Obtengo la posición de un objeto dentro de una lista.
    pos = self.busca_servicio(nombre)

    # Copio el objeto en obj
    obj = self.lista_servicios[pos]

    for atr, val in atrs.items():
        obj.atr = val # No funciona

    # Actualizo el objeto de la lista.
    self.lista_servicios[pos] = obj
```

Comment: ¿Qué quieres decir por "acceder eficientemente al atributo"? ¿Qué "eficiencia" buscas en un lenguaje dinámico? ¿No te vale una `namedtuple` o un `dataclass` (py3.7)? Faltaría ver el código completo donde creas los atributos.

Comment: Con eficientemente me refiero a no haciendo el animal añadiendo un montón de líneas de código para tratar de solucionarlo, que es lo que me venía a la cabeza antes de recurrir a vosotros :). Lo que pretendo hacer es una base de datos en la que creo dos clases de objetos con diferentes atributos cada una que luego irán relacionados en una lista de tuplas (operador, servicio) que gestiono con una tercera clase que será la base de datos. Pensé en dos namedtuple en un principio, y tal vez lo cambie, pero finalmente decidí esta manera por si necesitara diseñar métodos para cada objeto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sin entrar a valorar si existe una mejor forma de hacer lo que planteas, para lo cual se necesitarían conocer más datos de tu caso particular, para poder asignar un valor a un atributo usando una cadena con su nombre para identificarlo puedes usar el built-in [`setattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#setattr):

```
setattr(objeto, nombre_atributo, valor)
```

Vamos a crear un pequeño ejemplo simplificado basado en tu código:

```
class Foo:

    def __init__(self, nombre, id_=0, direccion=''):
        self.nombre = nombre
        self.id_ = id_
        self.direccion = direccion

    def __str__(self):
        #Cambiar por str.format si se usa Python < 3.6
        return (f'Nombre servicio: {self.nombre}\n'
                f'  Id: {self.id_}\n'
                f'  Dirección: {self.direccion}\n'
                )


class Servicios:

    def __init__(self):
        self.lista_servicios = [Foo("S1"), Foo("S2"), Foo("S3")]

    def busca_servicio(self, nombre):
        for i, obj in enumerate(self.lista_servicios):
            if obj.nombre == nombre:
                return i
        return None

    def mod_objeto(self, nombre, **atrs):
        ''' Modifica los atributos de un objeto'''

        pos = self.busca_servicio(nombre)
        obj = self.lista_servicios[pos]

        if obj is not None:
            for attr, value in atrs.items():
                setattr(obj, attr, value)
```

> ```
> >>> servs = Servicios()
> >>> for serv in servs.lista_servicios:
>         print(serv)
>
> Nombre servicio: S1
>   Id: 0
>   Dirección: 
>
> Nombre servicio: S2
>   Id: 0
>   Dirección: 
>
> Nombre servicio: S3
>   Id: 0
>   Dirección: 
>
> >>> servs.mod_objeto("S1", id_=43, direccion="Granada")
> >>> servs.mod_objeto("S2", id_=14, direccion="Tenerife")
> >>> servs.mod_objeto("S3", id_=17, direccion="Madrid")
>
> >>> for serv in servs.lista_servicios:
>         print(serv)
>
> Nombre servicio: S1
>   Id: 43
>   Dirección: Granada
>
> Nombre servicio: S2
>   Id: 14
>   Dirección: Tenerife
>
> Nombre servicio: S3
>   Id: 17
>   Dirección: Madrid
> ```

Como ocurre cuando asignamos vía `self.attr = valor`, si el atributo de instancia `attr` no existe es creado. Si quieres evitar esta situación, lanzando una excepción si ocurre puedes simplemente aprovechar el `for` para hacer la comprobación mediante [`hasattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#hasattr).

Sería posible también actualizar directamente `__dict__`:

```
obj.__dict__.update(atrs)
```

pero por norma general no es recomendable, entre otras cosas esto ignora propiedades y descriptores en general. Obviamente tampoco funciona el el caso de usar `slots`.

> **Nota:** Para evitar posibles confusiones, `obj = self.lista_servicios[pos]` no crea una copia del objeto en ningún momento, solamente le asigna al identificador `obj` la referencia del objeto (ahora `self.lista_servicios[pos]` y `obj` hacen referencia la mismo objeto en memoria). Si necesitas crear una verdadera copia del objeto puedes usar el módulo [`copy`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/copy.html) y, de ser necesario modificar la forma en la que el objeto es copiado, puedes usar los métodos `__copy__` y `__deepcopy__`.

Comment: Gracias. Todo claro y muy útil hasta que has mencionado los descriptores y slots, en tener un rato busco información sobre esto.